# Pandas scatter plot with density indication

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

How can I create [scatterplots](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) that would show how dense the points are?
E.g., given

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
df_flat = pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(range(100),repeat=2),
                       columns=["x","y"])/100
df_corr = pd.concat([df_flat, pd.DataFrame({
    "x": list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(range(100),100))),
    "y": list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(range(100),100))),
})/100])
def scatter_plot(df):
    ax = df.plot.scatter(x="x",y="y")
    ax.grid(b=True)
    ax.set_title("Correlation={:.3%}".format(np.corrcoef(df.x,df.y)[0][1]))
```

`scatter_df(df_flat)` and `scatter_df(df_corr)` produce almost identical plots:

[image]

and

[image]

(the only difference is the title).

How do I make the pictures different, e.g., by making the color more saturated where the density is larger (around the diagonal)?

Comment: Use smaller dots and partial transparency.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: yes, thank you, that's the idea - the question is how to do that.

Comment: `df.plot.scatter(x="x",y="y", s=3, alpha=0.5)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang: thanks, this seems to be the answer - where are these arguments documented?

Comment: I believe `df.plot.scatter()` has `**kwds` which is passed to [pyplot.scatter](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). Also the [pandas doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) has `s` option.